# 'Run As' Cucumber Feature is not generating the Glue Code for the Cucumber Feature file in Eclipse

Tags: java, html, selenium

> 'Run As' Cucumber Feature is not generating the Glue Code for the Cucumber Feature file in Eclipse.

> When I run my Cucumber .feature file it is not generating the Glue Code for the Cucumber Feature file.
> Instead it runs the previously executed .feature file.
> How to resolve this problem in Eclipse.

> ```
> How to resolve this problem in Eclipse.
> ```

Comment: i) Are the steps mentioned in both file same ? ( same in the sense they generate the same step code ( the content can be different )
ii) Right click , run as maven install -> in case you don't see any missing steps here , then probably steps mentioned in both are same.

Comment: Both the .feature file have different contents.

Comment: when you did maven install , did the missing steps came ?

Comment: Now I got the Glue Code generated by Cucumber. The mistake I did was, I have used  a name for the Cucumber.feature file which was used in another project. There might be a naming conflict. So I have renamed my Cucumber feature file. The issues got resolved.